# Entry contains 0 instead nothing

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm writing my first app in xamarin.
I load a Page that instatiate a new item of a list, so I binded some integer and double variables with the entry in the page. When the app load the page the Entry contains 0 instead nothing so I have to delete the value in the entry before enter my data. How can I solve this issue ?

[Actual Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLIyh.png)

[Desired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkwCW.png)

Comment: Just  replace double  with double? and int with int?. There are another ways but they are too complicated for novice.

Comment: Int and double by default are not nullable. Even if you do not initialise them, they will be automatically initialised with a default value of zero. To avoid this use nullable types: declare your variable as `int?` as opposed to `int`

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Willcock and Serge said in comment, change int into int? can make entry text null if there are no value.

And if you want to achieve the behaviour in your question can use the code like:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.text))
{entry.Placeholder="Value"}
```

or in xmal:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding date,TargetNullValue='Value'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a converter like this

```
public class NumericValueEntryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null || (value != null && ((double)value) == 0d)) return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { App.ValidateException(ex); }
        return "" + value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null || (value != null && ((string)value).Length == 0)) return 0d;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { App.ValidateException(ex); }
        return double.Parse("" + value);
    }
}
```

which is used like that

```
<Entry Text="{Binding DoubleNumber, Converter={StaticResource NumericValueEntryConverter}}" />
```